# Install python requirements.txt with Makefile only requirements.txt is changed

Tags: python, makefile

How can I run target `make install` only if requirements.txt is changed ?

**I don't want to upgrade packages each time when I do `make install`**

I found some workaround by creating fake file `_requirements.txt.pyc` but is **ugly** and **dirty**. It will refuse install pip requirements second time because requirements.txt has no changes

```
$ make install-pip-requirements 
make: Nothing to be done for 'install-pip-requirements'.
```

But my goal is to do:

```
# first time,
$ make install # create virtual environment, install requirements

# second time
$ make install # detected and skipping creating virtual env,
               # detect that requirements.txt have no changes 
               # and skipping installing again all python packages
make: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
```

Python package looks like:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── lambda_handler.py
└── requirements.txt
```

I am using file, `Makefile`, for some automation in python:

```
/opt/virtual_env:
    # create virtual env if folder not exists
    python -m venv /opt/virtual_env

virtual: /opt/virtual_env

# if requirements.txt is modified than execute pip install
_requirements.txt.pyc: requirements.txt
    /opt/virtual_env/bin/pip install -r --upgrade requirements.txt
    echo > _requirements.txt.pyc

requirements: SOME MAGIG OR SOME make flags        
    pip install -r requirements.txt

install-pip-requirements: _requirements.txt.pyc

install: virtual requirements
```

I am sure that

> Must be a better way

to do this;)

Comment: Can you explain in more details how your python package looks like? Do you use any kind of python project template? And why do you run make with `sudo`?

Comment: updated for @ovanes, added folder tree, and removed sudo because is not related to problem (lets suppose that I am root).

Answer (score 4):

@Andrei.Danciuc, `make` just needs two files to compare; you can use any of the output files from running `pip install`.

For example, I usually use a "vendored" folder, so I can alias the path to the "vendored" folder instead of using a dummy file.

```
# Only run install if requirements.txt is newer than vendored folder
vendored-folder := vendored
.PHONY: install
install: $(vendored-folder)

$(vendored-folder): requirements.txt
    rm -rf $(vendored-folder)
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t $(vendored-folder)
```

If you don't use a vendored folder, this code below should work for both virtualenv and global setups.

```
# Only run install if requirements.txt is newer than SITE_PACKAGES location
.PHONY: install
SITE_PACKAGES := $(shell pip show pip | grep '^Location' | cut -f2 -d':')
install: $(SITE_PACKAGES)

$(SITE_PACKAGES): requirements.txt
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it will answer your question at this point. The better way is to use a fully fledged Python PIP project template.

We use [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to create a particular pip package with this [cookiecutter template](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage).

It has a Makefile, which does not constantly re-install all the dependencies and it makes use of [Python tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which allows running a project tests in different python envs automatically. You still can develop in dev virtualenv, but we update it only when new package is added, everything else is handle by tox.

But, what you show so far is trying to write a Python build from scratch, which was done with numerous project templates. If you really want to understand what is going on there, you can analyze [these templates](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter#python).

---

As followup: Because you expect it to work with a makefile, I'd suggest removing the `--upgrade` flag from the pip command. I suspect your requirements do not include versions that are needed for the project to work. We made an experience, that not putting versions there might badly brake things. Thus our `requirements.txt` looks like:

```
configure==0.5
falcon==0.3.0
futures==3.0.5
gevent==1.1.1
greenlet==0.4.9
gunicorn==19.4.5
hiredis==0.2.0
python-mimeparse==1.5.2
PyYAML==3.11
redis==2.10.5
six==1.10.0
eventlet==0.18.4
```

Using the requirements without `--upgrade` causes pip simply verify what is in virtualenv and what not. Everything that satisfies the required version will be skipped (no download). You can also reference git versions in requirements like that:

```
-e git+http://some-url-here/path-to/repository.git@branch-name-OR-commit-id#egg=package-name-how-to-appear-in-pip-freeze
```

Comment: I don't know why but I still think that must me a better way https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=1390. I am expecting a makefile solution :(

Comment: @Andrei.Danciuc: ok, I offered the second alternative, by introducing versioning into `requirements.txt`

Comment: I know this thread is old, but: I have come here *because* I use the Makefile from cookiecutter (datascience), and it keeps re-running pip on every ``make requirements``...